# Generating regex to exclude a string in path

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex which includes all 'component.ts' files which start with 'src' but excludes those files which have 'debug' folder in its file path using

```
(src\/.*[^((?!debug).)*$]/*.component.ts)
```

I'm testing the following strings on regex101 tester:

```
src/abcd/debug/xtz/component/ddd/xyz.component.ts

src/abcd/arad/xtz/xyz.component.ts
```

Both these strings are giving a perfect match, even though the first one has 'debug' in its path. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are specifying a negative lookahead `(?!` in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^((?!debug).)*$]` which would then only match the characters inside the character class.

What you could do is move the negative lookahead to the beginning to assert that what follows is not `/debug` or `/debug/`:

[`^(?!.*\/debug\/)src\/.*component\.ts$`](https://regex101.com/r/vEo9Jw/3)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the line
- `(?!.*\/debug\/)` Negative lookahead to assert that what follows is not `/debug/`
- `src` Match literally
- `\/.*component\.ts` Match a forward slash followed by any character zero or more times followed by `.ts`
- `$` Assert the end of the string

Note that to match the dot literally you have to escape it `\.` or else it would match any character.

Comment: Note that that will reject paths where any segment starts with `debug` e.g. `src/debugger/foo.bar.ts`.

Comment: @Aankhen The OP states that this is about the `debug` folder in the path and that is also used in the example. I have updated my answer to use `/debug/` in the lookahead.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and their explanations, the fourth bird and Aankhen. Both work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches:

- `src/`
- followed by zero or more non-newline characters
- followed by one character that is not in the character class `((?!debug).)*$`
- followed by zero or more slashes
- followed by a non-newline character
- followed by `component`
- followed by a non-newline character followed by `ts`.

In other words, the `[^((?!debug).)*$]`, is not a lookbehind as you probably intended but rather a character class.

We can rephrase the desired match to see what we need:

- `src`
- followed by one or more path segments, each of which is not equal to `debug`
- followed by the filename

Which gives us:

```
^src(?:/[^/]+(?<!debug))+/[^/]+\.component\.ts$
```

(Remember to escape the forward slashes if you’re using these in JavaScript.)

[Try it on Regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/ivKIgH/2)

I added the `^` and `$` because I assume you want the entire input to match. If you’re searching within a large string, you can remove those and instead change both instances of `[^/]` to `[^\n/]`.

By the way, there’s no need to place the entire regex inside parentheses, as the first match will be the entire matched string in most languages.

Comment: This was the best RegEx answer I've seen just because you linked to the Regex101 tool. That's an amazing tool!